# How to get exactly all users from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-boilerplate

In **ASP.NET** boilerplate project.

I have a database with users. I am using standard methods for retrieving them `_userRepository.GetAll()` and deleting `_userRepository.Delete(id)`.

By default when user id deleted it is still kept in database with `isDeleted`
field marked as true.

My question is: is there in `ABP` any default method that retrieves exactly all users from database, and what follows:

is there any other possibility to do this than writing **stored procedure** like

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.AbpUsers
```

and using it in repository (and then in service)?

Comment: had you found any solution?? then share please, I am having same issue

Comment: No, filters did not work. I wrote my own stored procedure, and retrieved all users from database using it with proper entities and DTOs (just like any other stored procedure that is not default for ABP repositories).

Answer (score 0):

You should [disable filter](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters#DocDisableFilters)(`SoftDelete`):

```
//provided by DI
private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;

using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete))
//or
//using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete))
{
    var completelyAllUsers = _userRepository.GetAllList();                
}
```

Comment: Do I need an assembly or reference to use it?
I'm trying, but there is an error:
`Abp.Domain.Uow.IActiveUnitOfWork' does not contain a definition for 'DisableFilter' and no extension method 'DisableFilter' accepting a first argument of type 'Abp.Domain.Uow.IActiveUnitOfWork' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `
The other error:
`The name 'AbpDataFilters' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @Dawid, they all from `Abp.Domain.Uow` namespace from `Abp` assembly

Comment: So why such error appears if I am `using Abp.Domain.Uow`?

Comment: @Dawid, what is your version of `Abp`?

Comment: Dynamic filters appeared only since `0.5.10.0` version.

Comment: @MesamMujtaba, can you explain more specifically, what not working?